# C# callback function passing array

Tags: c#, exception, callback

There is a C code written to access an electronic device. However, i need to write the code in C# to access that electronic device.

C code step:

```
setPositionCallback( devNo, positionCallback, 2 );
```

The positionCallback function is called.

```
static void positionCallback( unsigned int devNo, unsigned int count, unsigned int index,
  const double * const pos[3], const bln32 * const mrk[3] )
```

In above code setPositionCallback - calls a positionCallback which then gives data through pos and mrk variable.

Now when i write a code in C# doing same job, i am facing trouble in calling positionCallback- i get marshal error and sometimes i get Exception Code: c0000005 and my code crashes.

Please can somebody help me to replicate in C# what is there in C positionCallback function?

Comment: this might help http://www.pinvoke.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
public void positionCallback(uint devNo,uint count,uint index,ref System.IntPtr pos,ref System.IntPtr mrk)
```

Taken help of Pinvoke